# Timeout when I call a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, timeout

From C# with EF, I call a long stored procedure with `ExecuteStoreCommand`

30 sec after the procedure starts, I have a timeout exception.

How can I configure timeout ? On the server or in my C# client ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could set the CommandTimeout on the underlying connection, but a much, much, much better idea would be to take the time and effort to diagnose why the timeout is happening in the first place.

Even if you "solve" the problem by upping your CommandTimeout, you could potentially be causing other blocking issues in your database.  Look for blocking queries or poor query plans, or badly designed tables and indexes instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
        using (var context = new MyDbEntities())
        {
            context.CommandTimeout = 600;
            context.MyLongRunningStoredProc();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings.toMyDB))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("myProc", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 30; // Increase this to allow the proc longer to run
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", myParam);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Patrice Pezillier is asking about timeout in EF, and your example is ADO.NET

Comment: How Can I pass the result to the DataSet? I am now with this technology.

Answer (score 1):

**Anything you do, other than fixing the SQL in the stored procedure is just masking the real problem (the SQL).**

You need to ask a question about speeding up your procedure, where you post your tables, and the stored procedure code so that it can be fixed once and for all.

Comment: That would have been very important information to put in the original post, don't you think?

Comment: 1 million insertions from a single stored procedure call?? what is going on with that???

Comment: Um, you're telling me there is never a time when a SQL query should take longer than 30 seconds?

Comment: @Micah Burnett, if you have an application that takes over 30 seconds to return data then yes, you have a problem.  Either you are returning too much data, taking to long to return it, or trying to do a back-end batch operation from your user interface.

Comment: Agreed in the case of returning to a UI, but what made you think he was in a UI and not a background task?

Answer (score 0):

Using indexes solved my problem, I found out that executing the stored procedure with ExecuteStoreCommand has not the same time as in SQL.

You can use the SQL Management Studio in order to find the index that you need, select you sql code for the stored procedure, right click and "Display Estimated Execution Plan" take the proposed index. This should optimize your stored procedure.